# AIR app signing without password

Tags: apache-flex, ant, automation, code-signing, adt

I have a build server that generates our signed packages for deployment.  However, I would prefer not to embed our passwords for signing the package in our ant file.  Is there a way to get around this?  It would be nice if I could setup something like how password-less ssh works or even use the keychain.

<rant>Why do Adobe products seem so unfriendly in terms of working in a team environment or when it comes to trying to automate them as part of a tool chain/regression suite?!  Don't get me started on the Adobe updater either.</rant>

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Adobe has done something for it. I guess you heard about AIRI files, when [adt creates](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html) AIRI, it not requires signing. Other than that, I don't think you can sign AIR file without using certificate password.

Comment: Yea, it's not that I don't want to sign the file without a cert password.  I was just hoping there was a solution that didn't involve having a password that's embedded in a file that gets checked in under version control.

Comment: I don't know about your workflow, do AIRI files help you? You can generate them automatically and sign manually/with non-committed script later.

Comment: Eh, not really but I think the best I can hope for is creating a password that is only used for the signing process and just deal with the fact that I need to check my ant scripts into git with passwords.  Just dawned on me though that I could create password file on the build machine that is read in by the ant script and saves the contents to a property.  That way I could have the password (albeit unencrypted) only on the build machine and not in a version controlled file.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I could come up with was to have a file with the correct permissions contain the password.  Then in the ant build.xml I have ant read that file in and set the contents to a property that my adt task uses for the keypass.  This way I can commit the build.xml file and leave the password out from prying eyes.  All I have to do is remember to create that file and set the permissions such that only the build process/account has access to it.